# How to solve broken characters by different charset between github and visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, github, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Now I'm using Github to help students download Visual Studio Project online.

But there's a problem. Visual Studio force me to use EUC-KR encoding. (I already tried to change source code files to utf-8, but visual studio were crushed and showed me errors.)
Because of it, My students are suffering from broken-comments by encoding problems in github. (especially some students that uses mac or linux in their labtop).

[Ref] https://github.com/waps12b/ajou.datastructure.2018.spring/blob/master/Week01/Exercise01/src.c

So I got some questions.

[1] Is there the way that force VS to use UTF-8 encoding in all solutions. (Not only me but also students that open this solution in their own environments).

[2] If I have to use EUC-KR encoding only in VS, How can I solve broken-charset problem in github??

[3] In some projects using VS, How they deal with this problem in development team?

Comment: Have you indicated the character encoding of the sources in the project? See [/source-charset: To set this compiler option in the Visual Studio…](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708819.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

"UTF-8 with BOM" incoding is compatible with VS and Github properly.

I used VS code to change file encodings.